# Northwind query with join on Orders and Order Details

Tags: sql, northwind

I have written a query like below using NorthWind.

```
select COUNT(o.OrderId) as Orders
from Orders o
join [Order Details] od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
```

The table `Orders` has 830 data. However when I join `Orders` on `Order Details` query gives me the number of data inside `Order Details` table which is 2155.

Why is the query result not 830?

Comment: Because normalization. There must be be more than record with the same OrderID in the OrderDetails table

Comment: Because that's not how a `JOIN` works. For every `OrderId` in the `Orders` table, you'll get every row that matches in the `OrderDetails` table

Comment: **@Blast**, is this for ms-access?

Comment: @Linger No. It is for MS-SQL and thanks all for their replies. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select COUNT( distinct o.OrderId) as Orders
from Orders o
join [Order Details] od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
```

It's because of the join.  The details create a one to many relationship repeating order ID in your results. The repeated ID is then counted each time; thus inflating the count to match record count in order details.  This can be avoided by either not doing the join, or by using a distinct count of orderID as listed above.

If you need any of the details from order details, or you want to exclude from your count orders without details, then you need the join.  Otherwise I'd remove it and the distinct as it's just generating overhead and adding cost to getting your results.

Additionally though, if you have orders without details then and you want them included, you need to alter your join to be a LEFT join not just an join (Inner).  As the join will exclude orders w/o details. If you don't want those orders w/o details in your count then an inner join is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check it as answer in 6 min :)